# Ajax .then() chains/promises with an If-Else flow

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I'm having some trouble synchronizing my `.then()` flows with an If-Else flow. The code becomes spaghetti and I'm not sure I'm catching `fail` at the right time or for each dependency.

I need the sequence

```
1. Execute `step1`
2. Check `status` var; if OK
    2a. Proceed to `step2`
    2b. Proceed to `step3` with dependency on step2
    2c. Proceed to `step4` with dependency on step3
Error Check: For any item in the chain, handle it with the error msg in `fail`.
```

Code:

```
function addEventItem(params) {

return step1()
       .then(function(data) {

            var statusOK = checkStatus();
            if (statusOK) {
                return step2()
                .then(function(data) {
                   return step3();
                })
                .then(function(data) {
                   return step4();
                })

        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert('A system error occurred and your action could not be completed. Please try again.');
      });
```

Can I be sure that

- Step2 will be chained in the right case, **only if statusOK = true but not otherwise**?
- Fail will catch all failures anywhere in the function?

Comment: Your parentheses / braces are imbalanced, so your question is unanswerable.  But yes; you're on the right track.

Comment: i mean... does it?

Comment: You can simplify your .then's to .then(step3).then(step4) assuming they both return a promise. (if they didn't, then your code wouldn't run as expected anyway)

Comment: @KevinB - even more so - you can just `return step2()` and chain a `.then` onto the original `step1()`

Answer (score 0):

> The code becomes spaghetti

There is no way around that. Conditional branches require nesting.

> I'm not sure I'm catching fail at the right time or for each dependency.

I'm not sure either, since it's not clear whether you chained the `.fail()` call on the chain started by `step1()` or the chain started by `step2()`. Only in the former case all errors will be caught (from all promises in the chain, including those returned from the callbacks like the promise of your conditional chain).

That said, make sure to use a modern version of jQuery and better use the standard `.catch` method instead of `.fail` (which doesn't chain).

```
function addEventItem(params) {
    step1().then(function(data) {
        var statusOK = checkStatus();
        if (statusOK) {
            return step2().then(function(data) {
                return step3();
            }).then(function(data) {
                return step4();
            });
        }
    }).catch(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert('A system error occurred and your action could not be completed. Please try again.');
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's catch(function() ..) without the 3 fail args. So it's always a good idea to replace all fail() calls with catch(), if we don't have the need to have separate failures?

Comment: The difference is that `.catch` returns a new promise for the result of the error handler callback, while `fail` just attaches the callback and returns the original promise.